# Disable to go back Mobile App Javascript

Tags: javascript, button, navigation, back

I have a problem with the back button of the Smartphones.
My app connects to a server and u get a session ID where it needs to work.
So when i log out from the server the session will be deleted and everthing its okay. Session ID saved local on the smartphone and on logout it will be delete.

Scenario: 
Loginpage ---(Log in)---> Mainpage ---(Log out)---> Loginpage

But when i log out and touch the back button of a smartphone it goes back to the Mainpage. And that shouldnt work.

The solution looks like: 
Loginpage ---(Log in)---> Mainpage ---(Log out)---> Loginpage ---(Press back button)--->App exit

So how can i solve this problem ? 
Hope u understand me :))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That solution works fine for me.

document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

```
    function onDeviceReady() {
        document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false);
    }

    function onBackKeyDown() {
        navigator.app.exitApp();
    }
```

Hope i could help someone too with this problem.